# Subscript unicode character symbol in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode, subscript

I would like to use a subscript infinity symbol (u221e) within a colour bar label in Python, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSOE6.png).

The following line of code allows me to do this partially, but without the subscript:

```
label="U/U"+u"\u221e"
cb=cbar.ColorbarBase(cax,cmap=colourmap,norm=normalisecolors,orientation='horizontal',label=label)
```

I would be grateful for any advice on how this line could be modified to subscript the unicode character symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually resolved this through trial and error. To correctly display the subscript unicode character symbol in the colour bar label, I changed the label string as follows:

```
label="$U/U_{"+(u"\u221e")+"}$"
cb=cbar.ColorbarBase(cax,cmap=colourmap,norm=normalisecolors,orientation='horizontal',label=label)
```

The resulting colour bar label:
[image: Colour bar]

Answer (score 0):

It was working as expected. Please refer the screenshot.

[image]